# Which fields have the property that every field endomorphism is an automorphism?

Tags: field-theory

That is the question.  Examples that have a positive answer include (I believe):

- finite fields
- more generally, any subfield of the algebraic closure of a finite field (since it is a union of finite subfields, and there's at most one such subfield of any given order)
- rationals
- the real numbers (since an endomorphism must preserve squares, hence is order preserving, so can only be the identity)
- more generally, any real closed field in which the rationals are dense (but not all real closed fields as I suggested at first: see answer and comment below)

I believe it is false for the complex numbers (for the same reasons that wild automorphisms exist).  Is that right?

It is obviously false for function fields.

Is there any general criterion?

Comment: It is certainly true for algebraic field extensions $F/K$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540936/if-f-k-is-an-algebraic-field-extension-is-every-endomorphism-of-f-k-an-automorp).

Comment: In characteristic  $0$ except for $k(t)$ and elliptic curves I don't see why a function field should have non-surjective endomorphisms. For real closed fields then $\overline{F}=F(i)$ but does $F$ have to be algebraic over $\sigma(F)$?

Comment: It's not true for all real closed fields.  It only works for $\mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense and must be fixed by any endomorphism, but that breaks down for a non-Archimedean real closed field.

Comment: @EricWofsey thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work to get a real closed field with non-surjective endomorphisms:

In characteristic $0$ if $k$ is algebraically closed then $k((t^{1/\infty}))=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} k((t^{1/n}))$ is algebraically closed.

Definition: $F$ is real closed iff $F(i)$ is algebraically closed and $F$ isn't.

If $F$ is real closed then $F((t^{1/\infty}))$ is real closed.

Let $F_0= \Bbb{R}$ and $F_m=F_{m-1}((t_m^{1/\infty}))$. Then $\bigcup_{m\ge 0} F_m$ is real-closed and it has a non-surjective endomorphism sending $t_m$ to $t_{m+1}$.